# Fixed Period Rollover Day

Tags: civimember

I'm having an issue where people signing up for a membership are getting an extra year added on (our fixed rollover date is July 1st).

All membership types are set to renew on Jul 1st (Membership Type Plan = Fixed, Membership Type Duration Unit = 1 year).
I've set the Fixed Period Rollover Day to Jun 30th.

When a member signs up for a membership today, they are being automatically set to expire on June 30, 2019 -- instead of 2018. Doesn't seem to matter what I set the Fixed Period Rollover Day to.

[image]

Am I setting something up incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

I set up same membership on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and it all worked as expected giving me an End Date of June 30 2018.

The system resets data every 24 hours but it is there currently if you want to take a look.

[Membership Type](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/member/membershipType/add?action=update&id=4&reset=1)

[image]

[Membership](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view/membership?action=view&reset=1&cid=203&id=32&context=membership&selectedChild=member)

[image]